# lightning date/date-time controlls other then ui:inputDate

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, datetime

Before i start my question, i need to enlist the list of bugs of ui:inputDate/ui:inputDateTime

1. displayDatePicker attribute does not hide/show the time selection button
2. neither ui:inputDate nor ui:inputDateTime is compatible with lightning design system

to add sadness html5 date-local is not supported yet in all modern browsers

So my question is pretty abstract: what would be the good alternative for those two ui components?

more concrete questions:

1. is there an open source lightning date-picker implementation?
2. can force's date-picker used in lightning?

It has been more than a year since i asked Salesforce to fix their date pickers. There was some progress, at least date selection widget is not duplicated for every single date-picker anymore, it is singleton now.

Answer (score 2):

Not tried yet, but it seems SF releases a lightning:input component.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm

```
<lightning:input type="date" />
```

may do something useful, who knows ^^

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! lightning:input is still beta.